# Need Help in Room Database

Tags: android, database, android-room

MyDao Class isn't responding the right way it gives me each time an error , need help to identify problem. Even though it is copies from a youtube class, and i checked the comment if there is something but everybody seems got it right.

```
    public class AddUserFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText UserId,UserName,UserEmail;
    private Button Savebn;

    public AddUserFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_user, container, false);

        UserId=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_id);
        UserName=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_name);
        UserEmail=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_email);
        Savebn=view.findViewById(R.id.bn_save);

        Savebn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int userid = Integer.parseInt(UserId.getText().toString());
                String username = UserName.getText().toString();
                String useremail = UserEmail.getText().toString();

                User user = new User();
                user.setId(userid);
                user.setName(username);
                user.setEmail(useremail);

                MainActivity.myAppDatabase.myDao().addUser(user);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                UserId.setText("");
                UserName.setText("");
                UserEmail.setText("");

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

   }
```

Comment: Which exactly error do you get? Edit question and add stacktrace please

Comment: as @Vasilisa suggested, add your error stacktrace as well as your dao